# How to get the value of stack pointer? (MIPS GCC)

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, mips, inline-assembly

I am trying to get the call stack, for some reason the following code returns a wrong stack pointer:

```
        unsigned int stack_pointer = 0;
        __asm("la  $26,  %[spAddr]\n\t"
              "or  $27,  $0,  $sp\n\t"
              "sw  $27,  0($26)\n\t"
              "nop"::[spAddr] "m" (stack_pointer));
        return stack_pointer;
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You aren't declaring any output parameters (declared after the 1st colon).  Where are you expecting things to get returned?  See the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#OutputOperands).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the stack pointer use the proper output constraint like so:

```
register unsigned sp asm("29");
asm("" : "=r" (sp));
```

Note that mips uses a register for the return address, but of course non-leaf functions might store it on the stack.

To implement a backtrace, you can however use the builtins `__builtin_return_address` and `__builtin_extract_return_addr` as described in the [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html).

Also, if glibc is available, it already has `backtrace` function, see [man backtrace](https://linux.die.net/man/3/backtrace).